# Fetch() sends error to console | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, console, fetch

I have a problem when I throw that. It prints to the error to the console (when I check by changing the path to wrong path and I want to see if I treat errors).

what can I do?

It means that if the fetch gives an error, so it prints the error into the console too (and not just going to catch).
And also if I will not throw something but the fetch will return an error (like 404), it will print in the console something like:
`Failed to load *path* resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
or
`GET *path* net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

```js
function f(path) {
     fetch(path)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status != 200) {
                throw response.status;
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
          // treatment...
          });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I did not copy well from my source code. Fixed.

Comment: The one in console has nothing to do with your code. It is a default console behavior for bad requests. You can turn off those request error prints in console settings if you want.

Comment: Hey, thank you.. So is it okay?

Comment: @ib2000 Well, no, it's not okay to fetch things that don't exist, but if you handle the error it's fine.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I handle the errors.